# Specify default Rails database

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sql-server

I created a new Rails project by typing the following in CMD of Windows 7:
`rails new simple_cms –d sql` , and I got the error:

> Invalid value for –database option. Supported for preconfiguration
>   are: mysql, oracle, postgresql, sqlite3, frontbase, ibm_db, sqlserver,
>   jdbcmysql, jdbcsqlite3, jdbcpostgresql, jdbc.

However, if I type `rails new simple_cms –d sqlserver`, then I look in the `gemfile`, I see the entry

> gem ‘sqlite3’

so why does rails disregard my given option for the default database to use (should be Sql Server)?? Isn't this strange?

Comment: But if `sqlserver` is specified as the database it should be `gem 'activerecord-sqlserver-adapter'` instead of `sqlite3`.  Which version of Rails are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
rails new simple_cms -d sqlserver
```

Works for me. I think you have some other weird character in place of `-`  (in -d option)

Comment: No, not really, my eyes are bad. when i copied his command, it didnt work, but when i typed, it worked. strange huh? thats when i realized that its not a hyphen :)

Comment: For me it didn't worked too when i copied his command.It worked when i copied your command.Yes seems strange ;)

Comment: I think he used double hyphen `--d `

Comment: I typed this in Word at first, which converted the regular - for me into a longer hyphen. Thank you for this, Santhosh!...Mystery solved. Can't believe it was this.